# Trying to make a scatterplot to do k cluster machine learning with an str

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, machine-learning

Im making a k cluster machine learning project using csv files from my ecommerce website. I want the two values to be Province Code, and amount spend on my store. This will eventually show which region spends the most money at my store. However, the province codes are represented as 'CA, QC, UT, ... and you can't really use a string for a k cluster.

So was thinking of assigning a numerical value to each and plotting it that way. Any ideas on how to do that or any public csv files I can find of anyone already doing it?
Here is a sample of my cleaned data.

[image]

Comment: Your question is a little vague without code and might be more appropriate on [data science stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), but i think the first thing you want to ask yourself is what does kmeans clustering mean in the context of categorical data (and what are you trying to predict)? even if you map `CA, QC, UT...` to `1, 2, 3,...` the euclidian distance between these doesn't really make sense. if you want to show which regions spend the most money at your store, you could simply plot spending by region – providing a sample of your data would be helpful too

Comment: what ML would be appropriate then besides kmeans clustering? i edited the original post and provided some cleaned data. I cannot provide the original csv due to legal reasons since these are real customers and addresses.

Comment: a sample of your cleaned data is sufficient. i understand that you want to use ML as an opportunity to learn and apply a more sophisticated algorithm, but ML seems heavy handed for your problem since it looks like you only have two variables. i would start simple – you could look at boxplots of each province and do a 2 sample t-test to compare the distribution of total spending between providences

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to plot the province vs. its spending. I'm not even sure if you need/want ML for this as without any other features than the amount spent, simply plotting and analyzing the graphs yourself may be easier.

If you have access to a list of the possible provinces, e.g.

```
provinces = ["CA", "UT", ...]
```

Then you shouldn't even need to convert them to integers to plot them. For example, simple plot them with matplotlib (a bar graph makes more sense than a scatter plot here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(provinces, provinces_spending)
```

If i've misunderstood and you do need to convert them to integer values, try this:

```
import numpy as np
provinces_as_ints = np.unique(L, return_inverse=True)[1]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it's nice of you to take the time to write up this answer, but i would suggest you wait for @ChickenJoe to clarify their question before answering because it's not clear what they want. i agree that kmeans clustering doesn't seem appropriate for this problem, but let's wait and see if OP can clarify what they want (or if this question even remains open)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will use a bar graph. However, for the sake of my resume and knowledge I still want to implement machine learning. Is this still possible if I convert them to integer values? I understand a bar graph can convey my point but I also want to be able to predict if that makes sense. This is my first time ever using pandas, matplot, and machine learning. I just finished my first python data structures course so bear with me